# Count objects in array by mutiple property value and display result in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The below script counts an array and displays it in the span element. Im looking for a way to do this with mulitple values and display the count in the second dropdown. in this example it would be the values of `standard` and `helskap`. The most ideal way would be to store the value from the first dropdowns radiobutton and add the second value. Whats the best way to do this?

```js
productList.Lockers.forEach(o => $('#' + o.model).siblings('span').text((i, t) => (parseInt(t, 10) || 0) + 1));
```

```js
var productList = {
  Lockers: [{
    "model": "halvskap",
    "modelname": "Halvskåp",
    "type": "Standard",
    "typename": "Standard",
    "family": "Berlin"
  }, {
    "model": "helskap",
    "modelname": "Helskåp",
    "type": "Standard",
    "typename": "Standard",
    "family": "Copenhagen"
  }, {
    "model": "helskap",
    "modelname": "Helskåp",
    "type": "Parskap",
    "typename": "Parskap",
    "family": "Copenhagen"
  }, {
    "model": "smafackskap",
    "modelname": "Småfackskåp",
    "type": "Standard",
    "typename": "Standard",
    "family": "Filippa"
  }]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="model" id="halvskap" value="halvskap">
  <label>Halvskåp</label>
  (<span>0</span>)
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="model" id="helskap" value="helskap">
  <label>Helskåp</label>
  (<span>0</span>)
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="model" id="smafackskap" value="smafackskap">
  <label>Småfackskåp</label>
  (<span>0</span>)
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="model" id="zskap" value="zskap">
  <label>Z-skåp</label>
  (<span>0</span>)
</div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="dropdown Helskap">
    <div id="Standard">
        <input type="radio" name="type" id="Standard" value="Standard">
        <label>Standard</label>
        (<span>0</span>)
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still not clear what you want *!*

Comment: Hmm sounds clear to me. The second dropdown has a span element after the radiobutton. I want to display the count of the array that holds both the value of helskap and Standard - with the prefarable way to save the value from the first dropdown (if standard checked) and add the value of helskap.